# Trying to run a PHP script in and HTML document with Apache

Tags: php, html, apache, contact-form

I am very very new to PHP, but I have looked everywhere (it seems) and cannot figure out how to run a simple PHP script on an HTML webpage using Apache. I am pretty sure I am doing something wrong or missing a step. I have a contact form. I have the .html with action=example.php.

```
<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="../../../../../../xampp2/php/www/html_form_send.php">
```

I tried putting the html_form_send.php file in both the php/www and the htdocs folder. 
Do I need to put the .html file in a different folder as well?
I tried changing the httpd.conf, but that did not seem to work either. 
Oh, and Apache is running. What am I missing? I would really appreciate your help! Thank you!!

**UPDATE:**
Thank you all for your help! I really appreciate it. I decided to use a different contact form, and it works just fine. I am still not exactly sure what all was wrong with the other one. However, I really appreciate the help and your answers did help clear up some questions I had. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Inside the xaamp/htdocs

create folder and put all the .html and .php files

Then in .html file give form action='html_form_send.php'

Answer (score 0):

You **may not run `php` on a `html` page**.

PHP would run if you have a `.php` file having the php code on the server.

In **XAMPP** :

Save your `.php` in `htdocs` folder.

**Start the XAMPP server and open the `.php` from the browser using : `localhost/<file_name>.php`**

You may also create folders inside `htdocs` to store php files and later open it as `localhost/<folder_name>/<file_name>.php` from your browser.

Also form form action just use `./file.php` to redirect to `file.php` found in same folder or `../<folder>/file.php` to redirect to `file.php` in another folder present in the parent directory.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I changed the .html file to a .php file. Also, I put index.php and the contactengine.php (or "html_form_send" renamed) in a folder inside the htdocs folder. I can open the index.php, but when I push submit on the form, it sends me this error message: [an error occurred while processing this directive] The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated. Please inform the author of that page about the error. [an error occurred while processing this directive].

Comment: In the form action give the php file name i.e. `action=file.php` and see to that `file.php` is in the same folder. Your error is probably because your action page is in a different folder or the file name of the action page is misspelled.

Comment: I played around with it a bit, and now it no longer says that error. Now, I get: 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp2\htdocs\contactengine.php on line 7.      Line 7 is the following: $Name = isset($_POST['Name']) ? Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name']));  I have looked for any missing brackets or parentheses, but I cannot find any.

Comment: You erro ris because you ternary operator only has a true statement. Use this : `!isset(<VAR>) ?: <TRUE_STMT>;` or you may use your condition and add this  `: NULL` for the false part  i.e. `$Name = (isset($_POST['Name']) ? Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Name'])) : NULL);` .

Answer (score 0):

You can not put php script on a html page. You need to create a new page and make it a php page of its own.

From your question i see you're using xamp. Create two different pages Eg Form_Receive.php (which will receive all the information sent from your form) and a different page to hold your form Eg. From_Post.php(which will hold the form and send all the information via POST or GET method.

Also be mindful of the url of the "form action" in your form. Once it points to the wrong directory or file, all information will be posted wrongly.